# vTiger 7.3.0 Uploading images with CompuMasterGmbH / cammUtils-vTigerNetApi

Tags: c#, api, crm, vtigercrm

Is it possible to upload images with the CompuMasterGmbH  / cammUtils-vTigerNetApi client?

I can create a product, but now want to upload an image along with it.
But as there is poor documentation in general there's not much to find on how to do it if possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is not possible, so we needed to add custom code to both the API client and the webservice of vTiger.
First you make a new webservice for dealing with the uploading of the file.
Than add code in the API for using that new webservice.